# Trouble with "Python Requests" username/password login

Tags: python, url, passwords, python-requests

I'm attempting to write a program that grabs data from my password protected gradebook and analyzes it for me because my university's gradebook doesn't automatically calculate averages. I am using "Requests" in order to log in to the website but with my current code, nothing seems to be happening. I've tried some different methods I've found here on stackoverflow but have yet to find a working code. Could somebody look at this for me? Thanks.

---

P.S. When I manually log into this website, it looks to take me to some sort of "authorization" URL for a short second, then it forwards me to the post login home page.

---

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                      maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)


import requests
url = 'http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/m/login'
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
payload = {
    'username': 'MYUSERNAME',
    'password': 'MYPASSWORD!'
}
r = s.get(url, auth=('MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD!'))
print r.status_code
print r.content
```

Comment: There is a bunch of js on that URL and most important it directs your login data to a d2l script: <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l" class="d2l-form" id="formId" onsubmit="return false;"> i guess you need a headless web browser to do, what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form that you fill in is on http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/m/login, but the form submits to http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l - you need to simulate submitting that form. I would make sure I had all the same information in there.

Stripping down the form I see:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="hidden" name="d2l_referrer" />
  <input type="hidden" name="target" value="/d2l/lp/ouHome/loginHome.d2l?isMobile=1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="loginPath" value="/d2l/m/login" />
  <input type="text" name="userName" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

Which, as @ABri has already pointed out, uses some js to mess around with it before submitting. When I submit the form (without the correct username and password) it looks as though that stuff isn't being changed so I'd try hitting the form in its simplest form.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {
    'd2l_referrer': '',
    'target': '/d2l/lp/ouHome/loginHome.d2l?isMobile=1',
    'loginPath': '/d2l/m/login',
    'userName': 'MYUSERNAME',
    'password': 'MYPASSWORD!'
}
r = s.POST('http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l', data=payload)
print r.status_code
print r.content
```

Without the un/pw I can't go any further but try that and see how you get on.